# Can you enable "log interactions to google cloud" via the Dialogflow API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, google-cloud-sdk

In a Dialogflow agent, there are two logging settings that you can toggle via the UI: "Log interactions to Dialogflow" and "Log interactions to Google Cloud". It's unclear how I can enable the second toggle programmatically on agent creation or later.

[image: The two visible toggles for logging on a dialogflow agent]

I am currently creating an agent programmatically via the [Dialogflow API Node.js Client](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow/latest/index.html), where I can enable logging via the "enableLogging" property of the properties argument in the [google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Agent.create](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/dialogflow/latest/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Agent.html#.create) method. Unfortunately, this enables only the first toggle and has no effect on "Log interactions to Google Cloud".

Alternatively, I've tried downloading the agent as a zip, and viewing the agent.json file. In that file, there are two fields that should presumably correspond to this logging. They are:

```
  "disableInteractionLogs": false,
  "disableStackdriverLogs": true,
```

The second line appears to be the setting I want to update. Unfortunately, when I change that value to false and import that into the agent, the second toggle does not flip to to on.

Is there any way to enable this either at agent creation or later?

Thanks!

Comment: I found this [enable stack driver logging](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-dialogflow/latest/Google/Cloud/Dialogflow/V2.html) for dialogflow but this is for ruby. I will still check if there is a similar implementation in nodejs.

Comment: This is not possible since this feature is not available for Dialogflow API using nodejs.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, @Ricco. I wonder if that log setting is to direct the messages from the ruby script rather than from dialogflow itself. I appreciate you looking.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.